# mvc path image in static html page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

someone knows how to manage path image in static html?
The problem is how to specify the images path INSIDE THE STATIC HTML so to work as online as visual studio localhost

Example : i have a home page and inside some static html page

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/custom_directory/home/static_page.html")))
```

INSIDE THE STATIC HTML :
1. if i use relative path :   custom_directory/home/img/image1.jpg
It works online but it doesnt work in visual studio localhost

2. if i use / :   /custom_directory/home/img/image1.jpg
   It works in visual studio localhost but it doesnt work online

There's a manner to work in both situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Url.Content()` helper method with the relative URL inside your root application directory, so it would work on localhost and on production as well regardless of what is the base directory name:

```
@Url.Content("~/custom_directory/home/img/image1.jpg")
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to use this code, sure this is code for mvc not for static html. What have i put in main page (cshtml) and in subpage (html) ?

Comment: create a cshtml view

Comment: sorry but i must use a static html page for some reasons, do you know if it's possible solve this problem keeping this configuratiom, main page cshtml and subpage html, thanx